# Passing Query Parameters Into Component EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a large number of query parameters to a route right now, and I have a component that resides in the route's template.

I want my query parameters to get updated upon change inside the component, so I pass in the query parameters via the component like:

`{{comp-name query_param1=query_param1 ... query_param=query_param20 }}`

I currently update the query params in the component with:

`{{input value=query_param_x}}`

However, this quickly gets tedious and overwhelmingly long as I will be passing in 20 parameters. Is there a way to make this more concise?

Note: The application I am developing is on Ember 1.12 and not using ember-data.

Comment: I seem to remember the latest episode of EmberLand (podcast) saying that you need to stick w/ controllers if you use queryParams in 1.x currently

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object that contains all your params, something similar to this:

```
params = {
    query_param1,
    query_param2,
    ...
}
```

Pass in the params object instead of each individual param:

```
{{comp-name params=params}}
```

Also, try to think if the component really needs that many parameters. Is there a way to break it down into less complex, smaller components, etc.

Comment: Are the query params actually updated in sync with those in the controller when changed in the component? You would need to observe all your query parameters instead of just stuffing it into a object right?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to not share queryParameters between a component and its host controller/router. Decouple the components querying behavior from the route's querying behavior. You do not needs these things to interact. Components do not need to share query params with their parent. I think what you want is to share is an instance of `DS.Store`.

By passing a reference to the store (bonus points to eager Emberinos who use a service to expose it), queries can be executed for components independent of the router. This way the store would be able to prioritise/marshall batched requests.

Here is an example mixin that implements this pattern. `store` is just passed to the component from the controller in the following way: `{{foo store=store}}`

```
Ember.Mixin.Create({
  actions: {
    // @params q Hash
    query(q){
    // #beforeModel just imitates the semantics of the route events  
    let [store,query] = [this.get('store'),this.beforeModel(q)];
    let p = store.query(query).then(function(results){
      this.set('results', this.afterModel(query, results));
      this.rerender();
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(error){
      this.handleError(error);
      this.rerender();
    }.bind(this));
    this.set('p', p); // P observers fire as it transitions
  } 
})
```

Comment: Hi @htmldrum - Just a tip for code formatting: instead of using the backtick, you can highlight the code and press ctrl-k. That way it gets syntax highlighting :)